# How to get Google Closure response with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, closures, compression

I have used Google Closure to minify JS code. I want to do same but with ajax. 
Here I have created FIDDLE for better understanding, where minification is working fine without AJAX, but giving some error with AJAX request, where Im putting response in textarea.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/64nsr3vp/`
```

Comment: Did you get an error message telling you not to link to JSFiddle without also including your code in the question itself? Your response to that should have been to put your code in the question itself, not to use code markup around the JS Fiddle URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong data format with the POST method for sending data to the server.
Please check the updated fiddle link

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/bpkhydcr'
```